# Can I route a mix of optional and conditionally mandatory parameters in ASP.NET Web Api/MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm guessing that the answer is to make multiple routes, but our route list is beginning to get long, so I'm looking to see if this can be expressed more elegantly and simply. :)

In my current example, I want to create a route that has multiple options, with some elements that are variable and some that are not.

So an example URI would be:

```
http://localhost/api/schedules/10/instances/5
```

And a matching route definition would be:

```
api/schedules/{id}/instances/{item}
```

The possible endpoints would be:

```
http://localhost/api/schedules/10 // returns schedule number 10
http://localhost/api/schedules/10/instances // returns all instances in schedule 10
http://localhost/api/schedules/10/instances/5 // returns 5th instance in schedule 10
```

What seems to cause trouble is wanting to have a fixed keyword between the two optional parameters. I've tried the following definition (and several variants):

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "RouteName",
    "api/schedules/{id}/instances/{item}",
    new {
        id = RouteParameter.Optional,
        instances = RouteParameter.Optional,
        item = RouteParameter.Optional,
        controller = "SomeController"
    }
)
```

With that route, just hitting /schedules/10 is not recognized, and /schedules/10/instances and schedules/10/instances/5 both return the schedules/10/instances result.

Is this possible in some way, or should I be making two routes, one for /schedules/{id} and one for /schedules/{id}/instances/{item}?

As a side note, I'm working on a Web API project, but as far as I know, that's just a specific case of an MVC solution, so I tagged both as MVC and Web API.

Comment: Basically, you can't make a literal URI segment like "instances" be optional, so "schedules/10" does not match the pattern. You can define two routes, or try the attribute routing library (http://attributerouting.net/). btw, attribute routing is being added to v.Next of Web API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can see my answer here for a full explanation of how to achieve what you want.

[MVC 4.5 Web API Routing not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318901/mvc-4-5-web-api-routing/17321724#17321724)