# Attribute routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I'm new with attribute routing with aspnet web api.

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [GET("users/me/brands/{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<Brand> GetBrands(long id)
    {
        return _repository.FindByUser(id);
    }
}
```

but I could not reach this action. I've tried so many ways:

1. `http://example.com/api/users/brands/4`
2. `http://example.com/api/users/brands?id=4`
3. `http://example.com/users/brands?id=4`
4. `http://example.com/users/brands/4`

PS: I also mapped as `[GET("api/users/me/brands/{id}")]`

What I'm missing?

Comment: Your attributed route says `users/me/brands/{id}` and you are using `api/users/brands/4` etc. Why? if you are looking to reach this action, you are supposed to follow what the template is suggesting...that is `users/me/brands/4`...

Comment: @KiranChalla api is the default prefix. Without it, mvc didn't route to my controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in the web api routing with MVC 4 and 4.5

A full explanation and work around can be found

[MVC 4.5 Web API Routing not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318901/mvc-4-5-web-api-routing/17321724#17321724)