# ASP.Net MVC IdentityServer3 broke my webapi routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So I am currently implementing security on a project I am working on and I followed the guide for identityServer3 to add it to my mvc5 application.  I got through the complete setup and thought everything was good, until I realized that routes in my api, unless they were the very basic ones, /api/.../ no longer work.

```
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I am using the default routing, and on the various pieces of my api controllers I have put route attributes to guide them in the event they fall outside of this format.  for example:

```
    [Route("api/Location/GetByAreaIncludeFileStore/{id}")]
    public IEnumerable<Location> GetLocationsByAreaIdIncludeFileStore(int id)
    {
        if (id <= 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        IEnumerable<Location> locations = _lookupService.GetLocationsByAreaIdIncludesFileStore(id);
        return locations;
    }
```

and as i said earlier, prior to adding identity server theses worked beautifully.  During the addition of IdentityServer I had to add a few nuget packages to my webapi:

```
    install-package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
    install-package Microsoft.Aspnet.WebApi.Owin
    install-package Thinktecture.IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation
```

So basically my question after all is said and done is, How can I fix my routes so I can get all of the information I need?

Currently I have routes that are

```
    api/controller
    api/controller/id
    api/controller/action
    api/controller/action/id
```

Any Help would be amazing, Thanks!
Also, I looked through many of the other posts and tried a lot of variations of routing and attributes before asking this question.

Comment: For example if I make the api call /api/area/2   The api should return area 2's information but now I get the response: "ExceptionMessage": "Multiple actions were found that match the request: \r\nDefaultAction on type XXXXXX.Api.Controllers.AreaController\r\nGetWithFileStores on type XXXXXXX.Api.Controllers.AreaController\r\nGetAreasByTourId on type XXXXXXX.Api.Controllers.AreaController", so the routes tags that have the actions aren't being recognized

Comment: Sorry I see ti now..

Comment: I believe that you need to define an action on your default route...config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "myController", action = "MyAction", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

Comment: If I make that change it results in webapi, trying to use(using the example /api/area/2 ) 2 as an action and the response is exactly that: "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44302/api/Area/2'.",
"MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Area' that matches the name '2'."

Comment: Decorate the Index method in the area controller with [Route("")] that should route a call with out an action to the index method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get it working using the method described in the solution in this post: [MVC 4.5 Web API Routing not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318901/mvc-4-5-web-api-routing-not-working/17321724#17321724) 
I tried doing this yesterday, and it didn't seem correct, but with a little more spit and polish I ended up achieving proper routes.  They recommended having the route config as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name : "DefaultAPi",
    routeTemplate : "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new {id= RouteParameter.Optional, 
    action = "DefaultAction"
);
```

and then following that pattern change all the basic routes like:

```
[ActionName("DefaultAction")
public string Get()
{
}

[ActionName("SpaceTypes")]
public string GetSpaceTypes(int id)
{
}
```

It worked, I had to refactor all of my api calls and my restful services to match, but nonetheless, I am back to functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your WebApiConfig `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` before your `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute()`.

Comment: I had that already, I just posted the routing snippet, sorry if that portion wasn't clear.  The solution that I posted is what fixed it.